# Can i reference in Criterion some Extended Attribute from another Powerdesigner XEM?

Tags: customization, extending, powerdesigner

Let's say i have two Extensions attached to some Powerdesigner model:

- xem_a
- xem_b.

In xem_a is Extended Attribute ea_a and in xem_b is Extended Attribute ea_b. In xem_a i can create Criterion with condition:

```
%ea_a%==true
```

, but i want to create Criterion in xem_a referencing Extended Attribute ea_b from xem_b. I tried:

```
%xem_b.ea_b%==true
```

and some similar expressions but without success. Is it even possible to reference Extended Attribute from another XEM in Criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the value of extended attributes coming from other extensions, you have to prefix with `.D`:

```
%.D:ea_b%
```

I didn't know it, I found it in [the online docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38628.1652/doc/html/rad1232022550549.html).